# import.io does not load any webpage

Tags: java, eclipse, import.io

When I import "**import.io**", it doesn't load any web page.
I use windows 8.1 / Win 64 and I have Java Version 8 Update 45.
I get the following "**error-protocol**" when the program exits:

```
!SESSION 2015-04-29 11:24:52.715      -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=1.7.0_09
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=de_DE
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2015-04-29 11:25:58.688
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: XPCOM error 0x80004005
at org.eclipse.swt.browser.Mozilla.error(Mozilla.java:2639)
at org.eclipse.swt.browser.Mozilla.onDispose(Mozilla.java:2658)
at org.eclipse.swt.browser.Mozilla$5.handleEvent(Mozilla.java:966)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1077)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1058)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.release(Widget.java:808)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.releaseChildren(Composite.java:873)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.releaseChildren(Canvas.java:167)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.release(Widget.java:811)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.releaseChildren(Composite.java:873)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.releaseChildren(Canvas.java:167)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.release(Widget.java:811)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.releaseChildren(Composite.java:873)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.release(Widget.java:811)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.releaseChildren(Composite.java:873)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.releaseChildren(Canvas.java:167)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Decorations.releaseChildren(Decorations.java:790)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.releaseChildren(Shell.java:1290)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.release(Widget.java:811)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.dispose(Widget.java:446)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Decorations.dispose(Decorations.java:448)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.dispose(Shell.java:715)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.release(Display.java:3808)
at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Device.dispose(Device.java:295)
at com.importio.builder.bootstrap.ui.SwtUI.loopSWTDispatch(SwtUI.java:170)
at com.importio.builder.bootstrap.BootstrapApplication.start(BootstrapApplication.java:47)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
```

Can anybody give me a hint on how to solve this problem?

Comment: Can you share your code, or give any more details?

Answer (score 5):

From looking at your error logs it looks like the Import.io application is struggling to bind with the Firefox browser.

Perhaps your install got corrupted.

Uninstall the Import.io application.

Then download and reinstall it.

Comment: Hi Andrew, thank you for your advice. I uninstalled and reinstalled Import.io. But nothing changed. I also tried to reinstalled Import.io in the administration mode. But there is the same problem, too. Do you habe another idea, how I can solve this problem?